# Plotly colorscale reverse direction

Tags: python, plotly

How can I reverse the direction of a colorscale in plotly? I am trying to use the [color scale Viridis for a marker plot](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#scatter-with-a-color-dimension)

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py

import numpy as np

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    y = np.random.randn(500),
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=16,
        color = np.random.randn(500), #set color equal to a variable
        colorscale='Viridis',
        showscale=True
    )
)
data = [trace1]

py.iplot(data, filename='scatter-plot-with-colorscale')
```

but I want it to be darker for higher values and lighter for lower values. Is there any way to do this without defining my own custom colorscale or changing my color parameter array?

Comment: I deleted my answer since my suggestion of replacing `viridis` by `viridis_r` didn't work out in Plotly. Still you can have a look here: https://plot.ly/matplotlib/colors-and-colormaps/#matplotlib-colorscales

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just add [`reversescale = True`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#heatmap-reversescale) to your plot definition and the colorscale is reversed.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
trace = plotly.graph_objs.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30],
                                     [20, 1, 60],
                                     [30, 60, 1]],
                                  reversescale=True)

plotly.offline.iplot([trace])
```

[image]

Comment: Here `reversescale` is used as a property of `Heatmap`, and it's also a property of `Marker`, so it can be used in scatter graphs too.

Comment: heads up this does not work on plotly express

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax thanks for the info! I'll check if I can add a solution for Plotly express.

Comment: [::-1] after the colorscale does it

Comment: in R it's reversescale = TRUE

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for this like me: contrary to Sheldores comment to the OP, for me adding **'_r'** to the colorscale name as described [here](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#reversing-a-builtin-color-scale) worked perfectly fine. However, I think this was probably changed in plotly since then. Compare the two following figures:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py
import numpy as np

y_data = np.random.randn(500)
color_data = np.random.randn(500)


fig1 = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    y = y_data,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=16,
        color = color_data, #set color equal to a variable
        colorscale='Viridis',
        showscale=True
    )
))

fig2 = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    y = y_data,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=16,
        color = color_data, #set color equal to a variable
        colorscale='Viridis_r',
        showscale=True
    )
))

fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

My plotly version is 4.11.0